# How can I improve my teacher-student relationship with a professor that ignores me?

Tags: awkward-situations, rudeness, school

I am a university student, in my current group there are only 5 students (2 women and 3 men).

One of my teachers has been ignoring me since the course started (approximately 2 weeks ago), that is, he never looks at me when he gives his class, he looks at all my classmates during the whole class except me. He also always asks them if something is not clear, except to me. This is something really very annoying because his favoritism towards the others is too noticeable since we are only 5 students in a classroom.

I always try to pay attention to his class, but it is really hard not to feel bad for his attitude towards me.

If I had the option of not going to his class, I would not go but unfortunately if I do not go to classes I can lose the right to present my exams.

How can I improve my relationship with this professor, so that he treats me the same way as he does his other students?

---

Note: I don't know why I am un-favored (I am just an average student, nothing special). If I knew why, then I'd fix it myself (let's suppose it's because of the color of my hair, then I'll probably dye my hair).

Comment: What interpersonal skill are you looking to improve on?

Comment: Well I don't know, whatever that might help, I've tried to ignore him but I can't. What would you do in my situation?

Comment: The problem you'll find here is that IPS is focused on helping improve an interpersonal skill.  Although the members here will sympathize with the situation, I fear the question will be put on hold because there's no clear course of action and seems to ask "what should I do".  Those unfortunately are out of scope here.  If the question could be edited to have a desired course of action, that would help.

Comment: @baldPrussian I've suggested an edit to this question to add in a skill.

Comment: You say it's discrimination, assuming you're one of the women, but there is another woman in class, correct? What  exactly accounts for "discrimination"? It needs to attribute to something. Have you talked to the other students about this?

Comment: It's **discrimination**, he's doing things for them and not for me (and it hurts) I don't know why, he's the only one that treats me that way.

Comment: @Sidar Yes I am a woman, and yes I've talked with one of my friends about it, her answer is: 'don't take it too seriously'

Comment: Discrimination based on what? I'm just trying to figure out what the discriminatory factor is. It's clearly not because of your gender. Is he familiar with your knowledge and study? It could also be that he assumes you dont need the attention?

Comment: I wouldnt call it discrimination because he didnt treat the other women differently to the man. So maybe is something personal. In that case you probably should ask in private if he have any problem with you.

Comment: Just to clarify: Details matter, not so people can tell you you're not discriminated against (you obviously are), but because the likely nature of discrimination (based on gender, dress, looks, familiarity, fear, etc) can make a difference to a good answer.

Regarding your question and the "off-topic" close votes (which I disagree with), you may have more success if you emphasize you want to resolve the issue *directly* with your professor.

Comment: I believe we're not being presented with something obvious to Isa. If you could venture a guess at why your professor acts differently toward you than the other four students, what would that be?

Comment: Difficult question. Could be anything.

Comment: I think the comments are getting hung up on the word "discrimination". At least in the US that typically refers to treating protected classes differently from others (e.g. women, minorities). Maybe "favoritism" would be a better description of your situation?

Comment: Would be the opposite for me then. Favoritism for my whole group.

Comment: Okay I edited the wording a little bit. Do you know if other students (maybe in other classes of his) have noticed similar behavior from him? Have you tried to talk to the professor directly, for example to ask questions about the material, and if so how did he respond?

Comment: @EmC I don't know if he has a similar behaviour with other students. I went a few times to his office (to give my homework) and he was rude aswell.

Comment: I think the intepersonal skill to develop here might be 'getting a read on confusing situations'.  With only 5 people in the class, the classmates may be able to tell you, if you can convince them that you just want to develop. That class is very small - is it an advanced seminar course for the best students? If you are an 'average student' the lecturer may feel that attending to you is a poor investment of his time in a stretch class for students headed toward PhD studies or something like that?  I'm really reaching for an explanation... Are your expectations for attention too high?